# Capitalization of n for sample size

Tags: notation

Should the n for sample size be capitalized?  Is there a difference between n and N?

Answer (score 11):

There is actually a difference in some textbooks: $N$ generally means population size and $n$ sample size.

However, this is not always the case. You should check in your textbook.

:)

Answer (score 6):

In terms of ANOVA small n (usually subscripted) could mean the sample size of a particular group while capital N might mean the total sample size.  It depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

small letter n refers to the sample size whilst the capital letter N refers to the the population size of the test

Comment: (for finite population methods)